# Strange lines in Away3D material

Tags: actionscript-3, 3d, away3d

I am trying to get the original material that object has and add the directional light that I have in the scene:

```
protected function onMeshComplete(event:AssetEvent):void {

    if (event.asset.assetType == AssetType.MESH) {
        myMesh = event.asset as Mesh;
        for each (var m:SubMesh in myMesh.subMeshes){
            var mat:MaterialBase = m.material;
            mat.lightPicker = staticLightPicker;
            m.material = mat;
        }
    }

}
```

As a result, as expected, I have the original material and the directional light. But my problem is that I have some strange lines as on the picture below.

[image]

Is it the problem with my code? Away3D code? Or 3D model?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Fabrice Closier has explained to me, the fix is to use repeat:true for material.
Here is the full answer he gave:

> Its not strange. Its because your model has uv’s values lower or exceeding 0-1. You need to set repeat:true to your material. The lines that you see are the pixels of your map (in this case the default engine bitmapdata) being stretched.

[Here is the link.](http://away3d.com/forum/viewthread/3578/)

Thank you, Fabrice, very much!